# How to use Local SSH Agent?

Tags: ssh

I just try to multiple ssh identities on my mac and this is my setting

```
Host x
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_x

Host y
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_y
```

on Host y everything work fine but x not worked, can someone help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Hostname is the same on both entries. 
Also check file permissions for IdentityFile in .ssh folder.

If this does not work at all try debug ssh connection with:

```
ssh -vvv user@host
OpenSSH_5.1p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8a 11 Oct 2005
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to host [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

Comment: Hi @mrks I follow this tutorial on Hostname
[link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-multiple-ssh-identities-for-gitbash-mac-osx-linux-271943168.html)

They have same Hostname

Comment: @alpiopio. In debug mode of ssh i see ssh is using correct id file which was given on config file. So pls make also sure that public key is deployed on the remote target as well.

Comment: thanks for response @mrks, this problem just occurred on gitKraken, it wouldn't detect my alias, but on source tree all working fine